# getClass().getName() returns null

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, testng

I'm using testNG to provide our test writers with a 'framework' to speed up the development of our tests. In order to achieve this I have an abstract Test class. All written tests are derived from this Test class. These tests can be run in parallel by testNG. Now I have noticed that sometimes in the @BeforeClass method my simple 'getClass().getName()' method returns null when executed in parallel.

```
private static ThreadLocal<String> className;

@BeforeClass
public void init(){
        initName();
        className.set(getClass().getName());            
        log("Starting test " + className.get());
}

private synchronized void initName(){
    if(className == null){
        className = new ThreadLocal<>();
    }
}
```

When I run this for a bunch of tests in parallel I get this output:

```
...
Starting test com.mycompany.testsets.LocalTestSet$IntegrationTest3
Starting test null
Starting test com.mycompany.testsets.LocalTestSet$IntegrationTest1
...
```

Some remarks:
Threadlocal ClassName must be static (I use its value later on in the @Dataprovider)
Since it occurse randomly and can happen for any test, i assume it is a thread safety issue but I don't see how I can make 'getClass().getName()' more thread safe.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the lazy initialization in `initName`! It is not thread-safe.

Instead, initialize the `ThreadLocal` field directly (and also note the `final`):

```
private static final ThreadLocal<String> className = new ThreadLocal<>();
```

(Btw.: Why do you need a `ThreadLocal` to hold the name of the current class? You can easily get it every time you want by just calling `getClass().getName()`).

Comment: I need it because I dynamically create the data inside the @dataprovider method which is static and i need to get the class name of the subclass inside this static method. I now realise the better approach was probably to use a testNG factory, but its too late for that now so i need a work around. I will now try your 'non-lazy' initialization :)

Comment: The read-before of the final really did the trick :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a race condition. If one thread calls `initName` before your other thread calls `log`, the new `ThreadLocal` will have no value, ie. will return `null`.

You have no thread safety here protecting the check for `null` within `initName`.

Comment: I assumed that the first thread that enters initName() would block the other ones since its synchronized. Is that assumption wrong? If it is, what is the proper way to block the other threads then?

Comment: @MajorT Your `initName` method synchronizes on the instance, not on the class, hence `initName` called on different instances will run in parallel.